# How to convert a character to a dataframe and manipulate as the previous one in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, character

I am new to r and I have problem with converting a class `character` to class `dataframe` that can be manipulate with its columns just like the original dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
library(RCurl) 
cv_today <- read.csv(text = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eparker12/nCoV_tracker/master/input_data/coronavirus_today.csv"))
cv_today_cases_10000 = subset(cv_today, cases>=10000)
```

And I have a character like `paste0("cv_today_","cases","_10000")`

What I tried is:`new_cv_today_cases_10000 <- as.data.frame(paste0("cv_today_","cases","_10000"))`

When I check its class yeah it is dataframe but when I want to manipulate it like `new_cv_today_cases_10000$country` it did not work.

Any help for this would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The code follwing "What I tried is:" does not work, `condition` is missing.

Comment: Thanks. What you're doing now is coercing `character` to a `data.frame`. `R` produces just what you told it to, which is apparently not what you're expecting. If you want to assign the variable `cv_today_cases_10000` to the variable `new_cv_today_cases_10000` just do `new_cv_today_cases_10000 <- cv_today_cases_10000`.

Comment: This is because you're just copying a character vector `cv_today_cases_10000` as the only value in your new dataframe. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `assign()` to associate a data frame with the character string:

```
library(RCurl) 
cv_today <- read.csv(text = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eparker12/nCoV_tracker/master/input_data/coronavirus_today.csv"))
assign(paste0("cv_today_","cases","_10000"), subset(cv_today, cases>=10000))

head(cv_today_cases_10000[1:5])
```

...and the output:

```
> head(cv_today_cases_10000[1:5])
      X    country       date update  cases
10  701    Austria 2020-05-13    113  15997
13  970 Bangladesh 2020-05-13    113  17822
15 1040    Belarus 2020-05-13    113  25825
16 1165    Belgium 2020-05-13    113  53981
23 1571     Brazil 2020-05-13    113 190137
31 2215     Canada 2020-05-13    113  73568
>
```

Comment: If we want to name it to new dataframe can we use new <- assign(...)?

Comment: @Ben10 -  If you simply want the result of `subset()` to be assigned to a data frame called `new`, there's no need for `assign()`:  `new <- subset(cv_today,cases >= 10000)`.